# C# Project Coding

Tags: migration, addition

When I add migration then it says that I have more than one DbContext in my project and to choice one to use.

I was expecting it to add a new class called InitialCreate into my project without any errors. also update-database to test the application is running successfully.

Comment: Please read [ask] and how to write a [mcve], and then edit your question to include all relevant details (code, sample data, expected vs actual behavior, errors, etc). Right now there's nothing but a general error description.